# How can I convert a Java object to protobuf's Any programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, protocol-buffers

Turn java object into protobuf programatically.

I am developing a log lib in Android. The interface of Log lib is`fun log(message: Any)`. Anything could be logged, maybe it is a String or a data class.

For avoiding log losting, it is stored in sdcard. To make log smaller, i choose protobuf.

I want to wrap the origin log with some extra info, so i write the following message in protobuf:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message Log {
  uint64 id = 1; // The unique id of Log
  google.protobuf.Any data = 2; 
}
```

My question is how to turn an java object into protobuf's Any programatically?

Or is there any better way to achieve the goal?

I have found [protobuf-dynamic](https://github.com/os72/protobuf-dynamic), but i dont event know what field is in java object.

Comment: Protobuf messages to my experience only make sense if you define them in the proto language, generate the model classes for your language and use them. Serializing arbitrary data classes to proto isn't the way protobuf was designed and thus doesn't work so well.

Comment: Protobuf requires to know the schema of the data upfront, I don't think it can (de)serialize just any object. There are some libraries that try to serialize just any data by introspecting it, for example GSON. They won't be as space-efficient as protobuf though. To optimize space you can look for serializing the data into Bson or MessagePack. Anyway, this is a very tricky thing to do. What if objects reference some non-serialzable or heavy objects like `Activity`? What if there are circular references? Usually, it is better to create schemas explicitly.